# Multiple slideshow for bbc-radio-1-zoom-tabs

Tags: jquery, slider

[The BBC Radio 1 Zoom Tabs plugin](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/bbc-radio-1-zoom-tabs/) is nice but I want to use it multiple times. What do I need to do to make this work?

The CSS is also confusing for images; are there any alternatives for using them?

Example

```
#one {
  background: url(http://...) no-repeat center center;
}

#two {
  background: url(http://...) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: It would help to provide a code sample of what you're trying to do - this plugin is not well-documented or updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked out the website and the source code looks dated and not maintained. It would be advised to use separate, well-documented plugins such as [jQuery Zoom](http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom) and [jQuery UI's slider](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Slider) as better alternatives.

Comment: Thats true but seems there are no any support for same pictures, only one.

Answer (score 0):

I rework js of plugin:

http://pastebin.com/D1WupuW1